How to use custom python module into langflow?
Ok, if we try to use the hosted version from Datastax, I don't see any way to install python modules into it and all custom components cannot be made due to the module not being installed.
Hosted by Datastax: https://astra.datastax.com/langflow/
If we self-host langflow, we are able to install the custom module as it shows:

But I still got the error, when I tried to use it in a custom module:

